# SPFx - How to get the URL and description from a hyperlink?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I'm trying to create a React SPFx web part which can render items from a SPO list.

I am having difficulty if the column is a Hyperlink. (I can get the value if it is a string).

Does anyone know how to render the value if it's a hyperlink?

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<ISplistitemsdataProps> {  

  const onRenderItemColumn = (item: ISplistitemsState, index: number, column: IColumn) => {

  const fieldContent = item[column.fieldName as keyof ISplistitemsState] as any;
  let typeOfThisObject: string = (typeof fieldContent).toString();
  let valueToReturn: string = "";

  if(typeOfThisObject == "object") {

    try {
      valueToReturn = fieldContent.toString();
      valueToReturn = 

      const values = Object.keys(fieldContent).map(key => fieldContent[key]);
      //valueToReturn = "<a href='" + values[1] + "'>" + values[0] + "</a>";
      //valueToReturn = "object:" + values[1] + "-" + values[0];

      const values2 = Object.keys(values[0]).map(key => values[0][key]);
      //valueToReturn += "object2:" + values2[1] + "-" + values2[0];

} catch (e) {
          valueToReturn = e.message.toString();
        }

      } else {
        valueToReturn = "not object:" + fieldContent;
      }
```

Comment: What is the value of `item` at first line in `render` method? Can you add value/object to your original question?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Hi Ganesh ... Its //export interface ISplistitemsState{  
export interface IListItems{
  items:[  
        {  
          //"HL":string,
          "HL":{
            Description:string;
            URL:string;
          }
          "Title":string,  
          "Id":string,  
          "Created":string;  
          "Author":{  
            Title:string;  
          }  
        }]  
}

Comment: If I do this it should get me the Desription and URL?
          const values = Object.keys(fieldContent).map(key => fieldContent[key]);
          valueToReturn = "values ..." + values[1] + "-" + values[0];

Comment: But that gives me values:two-[object Object] (it can find the Description but not the URL for some reason)

Comment: I am not sure about logic in your code. Can you simply try this first as first line in `render()` method? `let HLDescription = this.state.items[0].HL.Description; console.log(HLDescription);`

Comment: Also, Inside `ISplistitemsState` interface, Change `"HL":{ Description:string; URL:string; }` to `"HL":{ Description:string; Url:string; }` >> Use `Url` instead of `URL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperlink columns have data object/value in below format:

```
{
    "Description": "Google Home",
    "Url": "www.google.com"
}
```

So, considering name of your column is `HyperlinkCol`, you can get description using:

```
item.HyperlinkCol.Description;
```

& URL using:

```
item.HyperlinkCol.Url;
```

Comment: That was it... Many thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please **[Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)** and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.